# Fatal error while using evaluateJavaScript on WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, fatal-error, evaluatejavascript

`WKWebView` crashes while trying to evaluate JavaScript on Xcode 14.1, using Swift, tested on iOS but same behaviour should be on macOS.

I made a vastly simplified example to try to find a solution, and it keeps crashing:

```swift
let webView = WKWebView()
Task {
    try? await webView.evaluateJavaScript("console.log('hello world')")
}
```

> :0: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
> Optional value

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems that part of the problem is method overload, as of Xcode 14.1 there are several methods named `evaluateJavaScript` as part of `WKWebView`.

Due to optional parameters they seem to have the same signature, and the compiler is having a hard time understanding which one we mean.

#### Methods

```swift
open func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)

open func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String) async throws -> Any

@MainActor public func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScript: String, in frame: WKFrameInfo? = nil, in contentWorld: WKContentWorld, completionHandler: ((Result<Any, Error>) -> Void)? = nil)

@MainActor public func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScript: String, in frame: WKFrameInfo? = nil, contentWorld: WKContentWorld) async throws -> Any?
```

After testing different scenarios it seems that when using `async/await` version of these methods `WKWebView` expects JavaScript to return with a value (something other than `Void`), if there is no value returning from the JavaScript that you evaluate you will have a crash.

## Solution

#### Option 1

Always make sure JavaScript returns a value.

Crashing:

```swift
try? await webView.evaluateJavaScript("console.log('hello world')") // fatal error
```

Not crashing:

```swift
try? await webView.evaluateJavaScript("console.log('hello world'); 0")
```

#### Option 2

When not possible to return a value explicitly use the signature with a completion handler (even if you pass nil as the handler).

```swift
webView.evaluateJavaScript("console.log('hello world')", completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Wow, I'd suggest filing a bug on this one!

Comment: Good call @matt. I just did that: FB11770227

Answer (score 1):

another option could be something like:

```
@MainActor
func evaluateJavaScript(string javaScriptString: String) async throws {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) in
        evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString) { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            } else {
                continuation.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}
```